# Jade_form_input and readonly, how to?

Tags: express, pug

My toolchain: Node.js / Express3 / Jade.

I have tried to get Jade template interpolation to work with form input attributes, specially 'readonly' attribution. Trying it many ways, but not got any glue for this. Interpolation is working well with other attributes, f.ex 'value', but just this 'readonly' is quite odd.

This is working:

> input#f5lng(
>       type='text',
>       style='width: 70px;',
>       name='f5lng',
>       value='#{data.lng}',
>       readonly)

but how to interpolate with variables with rendering module?
Trying to render:

> res.render('modMrkForm', { layout:false, tid:req.params.id, data:d, ro:'readonly' } );

and intepolating in Jade with :

> input#f5lng(
>       type='text',
>       style='width: 70px;',
>       name='f5lng',
>       value='#{data.lng}',
>       = #{ro})

doesn't work. Neither just = ro.

Is there some trick to get it working.

Btw, rendering module knows whether this 'readonly' is required or not, so in other case rendering should be something:

> res.render('modMrkForm', { layout:false, tid:req.params.id, data:d, ro:'' } );

Any idea what's wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

it works this way:

```
input#f5lng( type='text', style='width: 70px;', name='f5lng', value='#{data.lng}', readonly=ro)
```

and

```
res.render('modMrkForm', { layout:false, tid:req.params.id, data:d, ro:true } );
```

just use an boolean instead of a string. i found it on the jade documentation, it's pretty good:
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a7

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you, this was the trick. I tried string_value but never got it working. I also found some this info about HTML syntax: //http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/blatreadonly.htm   so seems that XHTML requires value for attribute.  Anyway I can use this approach. Thx.